# Options to setting a integer to a value

Tags: c++

i've seen that some people initialize integers with "()" insteadt of "=". I.e.:

```
unsigned int a(1);
unsigned int b = 1;
```

Is there any side-effect using "()"? I know that this will probably have something to do with the contructor of an integer. Am i right?

Thanks for help

Comment: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an integer, it makes *no* difference.
For a class, it *makes* a difference - the parentheses would use the constructor; the equal sign the assignment operator. The two *should* have the same performance and outcome, but it depends on how they are coded.

There is a third way (and often recommended) way, using 'universal initialization':
`int a{1};`
again, no difference for `int`s, but there are advantages for classes. Read up about 'universal initialization' and 'initializer lists'.

Comment: "the equal sign the assignment operator." Well, sometimes.